# When did "pizza" first appear in the dictionary?

Tags: etymology, dictionaries

My friend said "pizza" was not in a collegiate dictionary from the early 80s.  He said he confirmed that recently when he found the same edition of that dictionary.  I know the word has been around for a very long time!  Was it just that one dictionary?  It seems like a collegiate dictionary would be even MORE likely to contain "pizza"!  Maybe they just assumed all college students know what it is...

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion which publications count as "credible" dictionaries, so establishing which of *those* was the last one to include any given word must *also* be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4):

The first English dictionary that *I* can find that contains an entry for *pizza* is

*Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary* (1953) ([Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/thinpaperwebsterthinwebs))

[image]

It also appears in *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* 7th edition (1963). This dictionary is based on the groundbreaking *Webster's Third New International Dictionary* of 1961, which was a descriptive dictionary.

The *Oxford English Dctionary* (OED) does not contain an entry for *pizza* until 1982, in *A Supplement to the OED, volume III*. The 1989 second edition of the *Oxford English Dictionary* also contains an entry for *pizza*, with the earliest given usage as 1935. The 3rd edition of the OED contains earlier references for *pizza*, and both it and Webster say that the earliest known use is 1825. (The OED 3rd also cites a 1598 usage from an Italian-English Dictionary, but the sense of *pizza* is "a kind of cake or simnell or wafer.")

The *Oxford Dictionary of Word Origins* explains:

> Baroness Frances Bunsen (1791-1876) was a diplomat's wife who travelled widely. A letter about one of her trips has given us the first mention of the **pizza**, in 1825: 'They gave us ham, and cheese, and *frittata* [a kind of omelette], and *pizza*.'

Here is a snippet from the online OED, which shows the publication history of *pizza* in the OED:

[image]

*Pizza* does not appear in the 1st edition of the OED or the 1933 supplement.

Comment: Hard to believe that it took OED 50 years to publish the term pizza,

Comment: Pizza restaurants were opened in London  at least from the '40s /'50s -  "*Although not the first, one of the most interesting Italian pizza restaurants in London was launched by the film director Mario Zampi in the 1950s and was run by his brother and sister-in-law."* -  https://books.google.it/books?id=FBMLFM305MEC&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=pizzeria+opened+in+london+1950&source=bl&ots=QlkW3XGc-T&sig=-397V5rnWJyAoYxs-hTSzOkw-nc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdyNG-6cfRAhUDtxQKHY-cDIkQ6AEIKDAG#v=onepage&q=pizzeria%20opened%20in%20london%201950&f=false

Comment: @Josh The OED was not churned out every ten years. There were no supplements from the one in 1933 to ones beginning 40 years later. See the OED's [publication history](http://public.oed.com/history-of-the-oed/oed-editions/).

Answer (score 2):

According to the following ***Italian [source](https://books.google.it/books?id=zciOrrmbJh0C&pg=PT61&dq=pizza%201935%20dictionary&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4wqbd_MbRAhVMOBQKHbnMAMMQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=pizza%201935%20dictionary&f=false)*** the term  "pizza" was registered in the Oxford English Dictionary in 1935.

> - Stranamente la Pizza, oggi comunque universale, sembra aver raggiunto l'inghilterra più tardi che gli altri due paesi, ***essendo registrata nell'Oxford English Dictionary con la datazione 1935,***  nelle fonti francesi e tedesche invece con le datazioni 1888 e 1879 rispettivamente

(Bootstrapping Information from Corpora in a Cross-linguistic Perspective)

- Note that the same date appears also in other sources like [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pizza) for instance.

The term was probably known and used in earlier years as suggested [here](http://blog.dictionary.com/whats-the-origin-of-pizza/):

> - In the US, Italian immigrants sold pizza in their stores, and ***the first pizzeria was opened in 1905 by Gennaro Lombardi at 53 1/3 Spring Street in New York City, but pizza did not truly not catch on stateside until World War II.*** Stationed in Italy, many American and European soldiers tasted pizza, and brought an appetite for this now-ubiquitous dish home with them.

(blog.dictionary.com)

Comment: Because words don’t get registered until they reach a certain frequency of use, you probably don’t need to hedge your statement with *probably* in “The term was **probably** known and used...”. :)

Comment: The word *pizza* does not appear in the OED until the 1980s.

Comment: @Clare - can you provide evidence of this?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. But briefly  there was no OED published in 1935. After the first edition, the OED was not updated until a 1933 supplement (this supplement does not contain *pizza*). After 1933, the OED was not updated again until further supplements were published beginning in the 1970s. *Pizza* does not appear until a 1982 supplement. The 2nd edition of the OED was published in 1989 and includes *pizza* and lists the earliest usage as 1935 (this is what your source is referring to). Subsequent to 1989, the OED has been in a continual process of updating. By 2006 the OED contained an...

Comment: .. updated entry for *pizza*, which includes both a 1598 reference to an Italian-English Dictionary (but whose definition of pizza is different from that of the modern one) and a handful of other usages that predate 1935. Thus, your Italian source, and Etymology online, is out of date. And your answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: @Clare - the 1935 date is from a number of different sources, not only the Italian one. I am not convinced by what you are saying and will do my own research.

Comment: Etymology Online uses the 1989 OED as one of its sources, so both your sources are dependent on the 1989 OED. Or are you saying that a version of the OED appeared in 1935–contrary to the known publication history of the OED?

Comment: Besides that, in an English language site  you ought to translate your Italian source into English. Let me help you: **essendo registrata nell'Oxford English Dictionary con la datazione 1935** means **being registered (i.e., recorded)  in the OED with the dating of 1935**. This means the word is "registered" ("recorded")  in the OED as occurring in 1935. The first OED to do this is the 1989 OED. (Unless the 1982 supplement–which is the first time in OED history that *pizza* is used–gives  dated usage examples; the 1933 supplement doesn't: it just lists words not included in the first edition.)

Comment: @Clare - so if what you are saying is true, OP's friend was correct about the date, but wrong about the Dictionary.

Comment: @Josh We have no idea what (collegiate) dictionary that the OP's friend is talking about. It could have been an abridged dictionary and/or some other dictionary  than Webster's. I've found *pizza* in the 1953 Webster's and Webster's dictionaries subsequent to that date. Both Webster and the OED (3rd edition, which is the online edition) give the 1825 quote as the earliest use of *pizza* in English (outside of a 1598 Italian-English Dictionary whose description of pizza differs from the usage of the last 200 years). The OED 2nd edition (1989) gives the earliest usage as 1935.

Answer (score 0):

Pizza is, of course, not an English word in terms of origin, but comes from Italy. Specifically the first appearance of the word, in Latin, dates from 997 AD in southern Italy, according to [the Wikipedia article on Pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza).

The use of the term "collegiate dictionary" in your question suggests you're interested in the American usage of the word in particular. The Wikipedia article tells us that Pizza (the dish) appeared in the US in the late 19th century, but that the return of veterans from fighting in Italy after World War Two led to a significant increase in pizza consumption.

Exactly when it a appeared in a particular dictionary depends on which dictionary you're interested in, but it's reasonable to deduce from the above that "pizza" was becoming a well known term in the US in the mid 20th century.

Comment: Interesting. But this doesn't really address the question directly.